# Python 2.7 / loop / break is changing my outcome

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, break

```
smallest = None
largest = None
while True :
    number = raw_input('Enter a number from -10 to 9: ')
    if largest < number :
        largest = number
    if smallest is None :
        smallest = number
    elif number < smallest :
        smallest = number
    if number == 'done': break
print 'Largest number is: ',largest
print 'Smallest number is ',smallest
```

I have no idea why my "smallest" is alright while "largest" outcome is always *done*. I think that "break" is somehow affecting it. Could You point out my mistake?

Comment: Hint: in Python 2.7, `None < "done"` evaluates to True, and so does `x < "done"` for any string x that is composed only of digits.

Comment: Your code for setting  of largest and smallest is different - I'd have thought largest code should be very similar to smallest, but with > changed to <.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter `done`, your loop should `break` immediately. But in your codes, you have put the break at the end. So before that, previous logic is being executed. And `done` as a string can be compared.

```
>>> None < 'done'
True
>>>
```

So your `largest` is set to `done` since `largest < None` in that case.

#### Quick Fix

We now moved the break on top, so this should fix the issue:

```
smallest = None
largest = None
while True :
    number = raw_input('Enter a number from -10 to 9: ')
    if number == 'done': 
        break

    if largest < number :
        largest = number
    if smallest is None :
        smallest = number
    elif number < smallest :
        smallest = number

print 'Largest number is: ',largest
print 'Smallest number is ',smallest
```

#### Handling Numbers

The `raw_input` returns `string`. But we want to compare numbers. So we should convert the inputs to `int`.

```
   try:
        num = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a valid integer')
        continue # skip the input and continue with the loop
```

Comment: Thank You very much. It finally work :-)

Comment: Note that this answer completely ignores the other problems with the code.

Comment: The only thing this fixes is not setting anything to `'done'`. It's still absolutely nowhere near the intent of the code.

Comment: okay, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are first updating `smallest` and `largest` even if the user entered `done`. So first of all, you should check whether the input is `'done'` and abort immediately before updating any of your numbers.

That being said, there are multiple other issues with your code:

- `if largest < number` – You are updating `largest` if the number is smaller than the previously stored one, making it have the same logic as `smallest`. Of course, you will not end up with the largest number that way.
- `raw_input()` returns *a string*, not a number. So if the user types for example `5`, then what `raw_input()` returns is the string `'5'`. So every comparison you make is a string comparison (e.g. `'2' < '5'`). Because string comparisons are based on character codes, this will incidentally work for single-digit numbers but you should really convert the strings into proper numbers first.
- You mention an allowed range of `-10` to `9` but you never actually enforce that.

Something like this will work:

```
smallest = None
largest = None

while True:
    number = raw_input('Enter a number from -10 to 9: ')
    if number == 'done':
        break

    # convert into a number
    try:
        num = int(number)
    except ValueError:
        print('That was not a valid number')
        continue # restart the loop

    # validate the number range
    if num < -10 or num > 9:
        print('The number is out of the allowed range')
        continue

    if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = num

    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print 'Largest number is:', largest
print 'Smallest number is:', smallest
```

Comment: `-10 <= num <= 9` perhaps?

Comment: @JonClements Only with a `not` in front of it, if we want a condition to retry.

Comment: Thank You, my main problem was with break and others I wanted to do by myself :D Thanks to You i got answers quicker. Thank You